# Running Linux application on windows

Tags: cross-platform, cloud, virtualization

How about running a linux application on windows platform without any OS virtualization.
Lets say we have an linux software installed on windows machine which can run successfully on windows with below mentioned approach:

A normal windows application runs on windows by creating a virtual address space on any Operating system. Program loader loads required libraries for the application from physical drive onto virtual memory address space. All those libraries related to application gets loaded when required by using File System APIs.

Now lets go in different way, instead of creating a virtual address space on local system, we can create a process address space on different machine which is capable to run the application. In our case, create address space for linux application on remote linux machine instead of local windows machine. All file system access can be grab on remote machine and transferred to local windows machine. In this way linux application located on local windows
machine, creates process address space on remote linux machine, access file system on local windows machine. All file system related apis can be remoted and routed to local machine. Linux application UI can be captured on linux machine and sent for display on local windows machine.

In this way different platform applications can be run on other platform as well without need of OS virtualization. What is your opinion on this approach and how much it is feasible. Is there any big fault in this approach which makes this approach non-feasible.

Comment: How is this different in functionality than using a remote desktop system?

Comment: In Remote desktop its not possible to run different platform applications on local machine at the same time... may be this approach can help in this situation...

Comment: Would this be similar to what coLinux was?

Answer (score 0):

That little word- `API` that you have used there means translating the entire set of system-calls of an operating system to another. Calls that go into creating a socket connection or a directory to file locking etc, EVERYTHING changes. You've discussed just memory here, the GUI has it's own calls, so do drivers and networks.

By the end of 6 years, that little million-line of code that you would've written to achieve all this, when packaged and bundled, will be called; surprise, surprise- a hypervisor.